# How does one compare a row with its preceding row in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, comparison

I'm trying to find the difference between every row with its preceding row in a table.

When I say difference, I mean whether two values are the same or not.

I'm not sure if I need a for loop, and also if the table has 30 to 40 columns does that mean that I will have to write the check for each of those 30-40 columns ?

- Row1 - ID1 - data1 - data2 - data3..
- Row2 - ID1 - data1 - data2 - data3..
- Row3 - ID2 - data1 - data2 - data3..
- Row4 - ID1 - data1 - data2 - data3..

  ```
  for i = 2 .. 3
  is Row[i][data1] != Row[i-1][data1], Row[i][data2] != Row[i-1][data2]....
  ```

This check needs to be done for all records with the same Non-Unique ID. ie. ID1 can exist for more than one record. 
Rows with ID1 needs to be compared with other rows of ID1.

Comment: What are you ordering by? There is no order unless there is an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: So far the data is in a table, there is a field that will be used to order the data.

Once this procedure / code finishes running, then the data has to be outputted.

Comment: If this can be done within SQL it would be great.

Comment: could you post a table with sample data and required o/p ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Oracle `lag` analitic function. Let us assume that your table is this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (no int, id int, val1 int, val2 int)
```

where `no` is the field on which data is ordered, `id` is your non-unique identifier (group identifier), `val1` and `val2` are values. Than you can use this query to find if each row is a duplicate of the previous row in its group:

```
select no, id, val1, val2,
 case when
  lag(val1,1) over (partition by id order by no) = val1 and
  lag(val2,1) over (partition by id order by no) = val2
 then 1 else 0 end duplicate
from tbl
order by no
```

[Here it is in SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/872e6/2)

Comment: This is really great but here it checks if the entire row is equal to the previous row, how would I check if one or two columns differ from the previous one ?
Ie. I do not see if each row is equal to the previous one, I need to check which of the fields are not equal to the fields of the previous row.

Comment: `INTO tbl (no, id, val1, val2)
   VALUES (2, 1, 3, 3)
 INTO tbl (no, id, val1, val2)
   VALUES (3, 1, 3, 4)`

using the above statements.
I have the first `val1` = the second `val1` ie. `3 == 3`,
but the first `val2 !=` the second `val2` ie. `3 != 4`,

How would I detect that ?

Comment: Or like this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cebe7/2 ? (The difference is that first row in a group is considered having all columns changed)

Comment: Am I limited to `Then 1 else 0` or can is there a way of doing :
`then update tb1 set val1 = SomeValue else update tb1 set val1=NULL`

btw, thanks for all your help! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @user1283103 You definitely can not do updates inside select. But you can use similar constructs in where-caluse of your update.

Comment: @user1283103 "thanks" - If you tell more about your updating task in the question I will be able to post more code for it. 
And do not forget to tick-select right answers - it gives *you* +2 reputation points!

Answer (score 0):

try this !!

comparing a table with it's own PK's

```
 select t1.value - t2.value from table t1, table t2 
    where t1.primaryKey = t2.primaryKey - 1
```